# Dynamic Facebook Like

Tags: python, django, facebook

I have a news app on my website.
I added a Facebook like button on every news/post page but i can’t get it working correctly.

When I click on the like button, it changes state which is ok but changes are not affected - displayed on the actual Facebook page.

Can anybody share their experiences?

This is what i tried so far

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mysite.com/posts/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mysite.com/news/{{ object.title }}" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the Like button to like posts.

It works only for Facebook pages, or external Open Graph objects.